# Why should unit vectors that get linearly mapped to the semi-axes of an ellipse be orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I'm reading [Wikipedia's visual proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Geometric_meaning) of the singular value decomposition. They say:

> To get a more visual flavor of singular values and SVD factorization – at least when working on real vector spaces – consider the sphere $S$ of radius one in $\mathbb R^n$. The linear map $T$ maps this sphere onto an ellipsoid in $\mathbb R^m$. Non-zero singular values are simply the lengths of the semi-axes of this ellipsoid. Especially when $n = m$, and all the singular values are distinct and non-zero, the SVD of the linear map $T$ can be easily analyzed as a succession of three consecutive moves: consider the ellipsoid $T(S)$ and specifically its axes; then consider the directions in $\mathbb R^n$ sent by $T$ onto these axes. **These directions happen to be mutually orthogonal.**
>
> Apply first an isometry $V^⁎$ sending these directions to the coordinate axes of $\mathbb R^n$. On a second move, apply an endomorphism $D$ diagonalized along the coordinate axes and stretching or shrinking in each direction, using the semi-axes lengths of $T(S)$ as stretching coefficients. The composition $D \circ V^⁎$ then sends the unit-sphere onto an ellipsoid isometric to $T(S)$. To define the third and last move $U$, apply an isometry to this ellipsoid so as to carry it over $T(S)$. As can be easily checked, the composition $U \circ D \circ V^⁎$ coincides with $T$.

Why should unit vectors that get linearly mapped to the semi-axes of an ellipse be orthogonal? Is there a neat mathematical argument for this?

Comment: Thinking in terms of matrices $T=UDV^*$, these "directions" in your bolded statement are the columns of $V$, and you can check that $T$ maps columns of $V$ to [scaled] columns of $U$ which are the ellipsoid axes. In the derivation of SVD, the columns of $V$ are the elements of the eigenbasis of $T^* T$, which by the spectral theorem can be chosen to be orthonormal.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks, but this line of thinking only works once you already know the SVD formula. Is there any other way to see this without using $T = UDV^*$?